# Problem converting CSV to JSON file using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs

I'm trying to convert csv file into Json file using javascript and I'm faced with unexpected problem.

Here is my CSV file...

[image]

And here is my csvToJSON.js

```
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from "fs";
import papaparse  from "papaparse";
try {
  const csvFile = readFileSync("./testData/test.csv", "utf8");
  const csvResults = papaparse.parse(csvFile, {
    header: true,
    complete: csvData => csvData.data
  }).data;
  writeFileSync(
    "./cypress/fixtures/testDataFromCSV.json",
    JSON.stringify(csvResults, null, 4),
    "utf-8"
  );
} catch (e) {
  throw Error(e);
}
```

My converted json file(testDataFromCSV.json) looks like this..

```
[
    {
        "id": "Id1",
        "password": "password1",
        "name": "name1",
        "": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "Id2",
        "password": "password2",
        "name": "name2",
        "": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "Id3",
        "password": "password3",
        "name": "name3",
        "": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "" // 
    }
]
```

In my csv file, there is no data in the forth row, but when I console.log(csvFile)

```
Id1,password1,name1,,,,
Id2,password2,name2,,,,
Id3,password3,name3,,,,
```

How to prevent my javascript code from pushing empty row in csv file? Please help me to resolve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config shows that there’s an option `skipEmptyLines`, with default value `false`.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! Now empty rows can't be converted into json file. Do you have any idea why does 'fs.readFileSync' read empty column("":"")?